Ubuntu 24.04.1 desktop install crashes on ThinkPad Z13 gen2
I'm currently on Ubuntu 22.04 and trying to install from scratch 24.04.1. However, install crashes every time around after disk selection is done. I have tried

with and without wifi,
with default graphics and safe graphics options, and also
tried to set the laptop in airplane mode after boot

Still the same "Something went wrong" crash. The last 7 things on "Something went wrong" log is following:
subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config:
subiquity/Zdev/apply_autoinstall_config:
subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config:
subiquity/Ad/apply_autoinstall_config:
subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config:
subiquity/Late/apply_autoinstall_config:
subiquity/Ad/has_support_GET:

Any ideas? Thanks.

Do you have Pluton? Lenovo's new AMD Rembrandt powered laptops with Microsoft Pluton security co-processor are set by default to only trust Microsoft's key or the only boot Windows. ThinkPad Z13
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Lenovo-Pluton-Windows-Default
Lenovo with Linux support (says Z13 has UEFI setting to turn off  Pluton)
https://www.phoronix.com/news/Lenovo-Linux-2022-State Thinkpad Z13 Gen 2 - enable "third-party" UEFI certificates i
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2497496

I have the secure boot turned off. Besides, Ubuntu 22.04 install works fine, only 24.04 crashes.

One user posted that he closed installer, then restarted it without reboot & it then worked.
